# How can I use $uid in a security rule to enable users to write to a collection for the first time without allowing them to overwrite other users data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

**Background**

I have a website with a public messaging board and want authenticated users to add posts to the collection (writing). However I do not want the users to overwrite posts that dont belong to them (posts from other users).
The only way I know of is using the $uid===$uid parameter in a rule like below:

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "posts":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
      }
```

**Problem**

Using the $uid parameter requires the uid to already exist in the posts array. So I am confused about this circular reference. Basically you need the data to exist in the collection to be able to write to it but you cant write to the collection because collection doesn’t contain the data (with the matching uid).

Would apprecite any ideas or pointers for how I can proceed forwards to break this circular reference. How do other apps that use firebase in the backend, secure their write rules with such a conundrum?

For reference, this is a print screen of my database collection when a user adds a post. [image]

**Edited on 18th September to clear any confusion in the comment threads below. I am including the write rules which have worked and to further demonstrate the problem I am having with uid===$uid rule**

1. this write rule works but is very insecure because it allows anyone to write/edit other user data.

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "posts":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": true
      }
```

2. this write rule works but is still insecure because authenticated users can write/edit other user data.

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "posts":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
      }
```

3. The write rule which I am having trouble with, is already in the **Background** section above.

**To refine the question and so that we can all get as clear and straight an answer as possible. Why is this 3rd rule which has the $uid parameter interfering with my ability to write compared to rules 1 and 2 above?**

Edited as requested to include the relevant Back-end code that the rule is supposed to work against:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  ComponentSize,
  UserNoLongerActive,
} from '../../../../libs/constants/constants';
import { NgbTooltip } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { OjasPointsComponent } from '../../../../libs/components/ojas-points/ojas-points.component';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { TribeLogoComponent } from '../../../../libs/components/semen-components/tribe-logo/tribe-logo.component';
import {
  OjasPointsOperation,
  ShareExperiencePayload,
} from '../../../../libs/types/types';
import { BenefitUserExperienceService } from '../benefit-user-experience.service';
import { OjasPointsService } from '../../../../libs/services/ojas-points.service';
import { UserService } from '../../../../libs/services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-benefit-user-experience',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbTooltip,
    OjasPointsComponent,
    RouterLink,
    TribeLogoComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './benefit-user-experience.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./benefit-user-experience.component.scss'],
})
export class BenefitUserExperienceComponent {
  @Input() public experience: ShareExperiencePayload;

  public username: string;
  protected readonly ComponentSize = ComponentSize;

  constructor(
    private readonly benefitUserExperienceService: BenefitUserExperienceService,
    private readonly ojasPointsService: OjasPointsService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.username =
      this.userService.getUserDataFromLocalStorage().userInfo.username;
  }

  public incrementVoteCounter($event: any) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    let updatedExperience: ShareExperiencePayload | undefined = this.experience;

    if (updatedExperience) {
      updatedExperience.voteCounter++;
      updatedExperience.usersListWhoLikedTheExperience.push(this.username);
      updatedExperience.usersListWhoDislikedTheExperience =
        updatedExperience.usersListWhoDislikedTheExperience.filter(
          (item) => item !== this.username,
        );

      this.benefitUserExperienceService
        .updateBenefitUserExperience(updatedExperience)
        .then(async () => {
          if (updatedExperience?.userId) {
            await this.ojasPointsService.UpdateOjasPoints({
              userUid: updatedExperience?.userId,
              operation: OjasPointsOperation.increment,
              amount: 0.5,
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('error occurred while updating database', error);
        });
    }
  }

  public decrementVoteCounter($event: any) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    let updatedExperience: ShareExperiencePayload | undefined = this.experience;

    if (updatedExperience) {
      updatedExperience.voteCounter--;
      updatedExperience.usersListWhoDislikedTheExperience.push(this.username);
      updatedExperience.usersListWhoLikedTheExperience =
        updatedExperience.usersListWhoLikedTheExperience.filter(
          (item) => item !== this.username,
        );

      this.benefitUserExperienceService
        .updateBenefitUserExperience(updatedExperience)
        .then(async () => {
          if (updatedExperience?.userId) {
            await this.ojasPointsService.UpdateOjasPoints({
              userUid: updatedExperience?.userId,
              operation: OjasPointsOperation.decrement,
              amount: 0.5,
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('error occurred while updating database', error);
        });
    }
  }

  protected readonly UserNoLongerActive = UserNoLongerActive;
}
```

Comment: What does not work with your rule? It allows setting and updating data of a RTDB node under `posts` with a key that is equal to the user's uid. You write "Using the $uid parameter requires the uid to already exist in the posts array.". What do you mean by "posts array"?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that doesn't work against these security rules.

Comment: Hi Renaud, let me clarify with an example. Lets say no one has added data to the posts node before. Say you were the first user with a uid of Renaud212 to add data to the node (node = what I mean by the array). From my understanding, if you have the condition ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid", then you wont be able to write  to the node "posts" because the rule will check and see there is no data in existence with a uid of Renaud212. So that’s where I am stuck. How can I let users add data to the node when the rule requires their data and uid to already exist in the node.

Comment: Hi Frank I've edited the question to include the code. The software developer that I hired is the one who wrote this code so I dont have a deep understanding of it. However the one thing I noticed is it references "user id" rather than "uid"

Comment: @JKxbt33 Use `@` to notify users.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec just commenting here to notify you

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen also notifying you of the edit. Cheers

Comment: Hi @JKxbt33 your above statement (« you wont be able to write to the node "posts" because the rule will check and see there is no data in existence with a uid of Renaud212») is not correct. As said in my comment you can **create** and update with your current rule

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec, I didnt know you could do this. When I checked the documentation they only gave options to 1.read, 2.write, 3.validate and 4.indexon. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Do you mind answering with an example of how this can be done? As I cant find an example from google's documentation for "create" in security rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to clarify the missing rules not mentioned here.

Consider not any of those 3 rules, but the following:

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "posts": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && !data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here you will be able to create new entry only, without the ability to edit. Notice that "$uid" key is not used here.

Now let's add another condition to also allow user to edit

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "posts": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now we have rule that allow us to create and also edit existing "posts" for the particular $uid key.

Now for the sake of learning purposes, let's take a look of the following rule:

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "posts":{
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      ".write": "!data.exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the missing child key $uid, it is now directly under the "posts" object itself. This entry actually will make you can't create anything under the posts if you have existing "posts" object already, because the "posts" data already exist in that particular closure.

**Code for testing auth trying to access other userId**

```
/** Sample code for frontend, need to be adjusted for backend */
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set, child } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-database.js";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const dbRef = ref(db);

// Run this code after authentication (login)
//const userId = auth.currentUser.uid; // uncomment to test the authorized one.
const userId = "SomeOtherUserUid"; // use other userId key to test the unauthorized, comment it out to test the authorized one.
set(child(dbRef, `posts/${userId}`), {
  "test": "isWorking"
});
```

Comment: Thanks @arifnpm this is perfect and what I've been looking for all this time. the second rule you've posted is now working when tested on the posts collection. Before I upvote this as the answer, how can I prove the rule is doing what its meant to do? what I mean, is there a way in realtime database to login as another user and try to write/edit another user's data? maybe using some querying command?

Comment: Hi @JKxbt33, great to know it is working. As firebase realtime db is tied with firebase authentication, the auth value always come from the authentication. However, the query come from the code in backend/frontend. You can try the new code edited in the answer.

Comment: HI @arifnpm I found the easiest way to test whether your rule works or not is to use the firebase security rules playground. Unfortnately I am having trouble proving your rule works so I've created a new thread to get this troubleshooted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151970/read-and-write-rules-fail-on-the-firebase-security-rules-playground-although-wri

Comment: Thanks Arif, I've now confirmed after testing that your rule works on the firebase security rules playground. I can confirm that a) I am able to add data to the collection for the first time b) users are unable to overwrite/update other users data

Answer (score 1):

*Following the comments under your question, and in particular "Do you mind answering with an example of how this can be done? As I cant find an example from google's documentation for "create" in security rules."*

Your following write rule

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "posts":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

does allow:

1. Creating (i.e. setting) data of a RTDB node under the `posts` node with a key that is equal to the user's uid.
2. Updating such a node

Of course the user must be authenticated in order for this rule to work.

---

Note that the [**write** rules type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database?hl=en&authuser=0#write) actually covers creating **and** updating. There isn't any rules type specifically dedicated to creation, nor another type specifically dedicated to updating, like we find in [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?hl=en&authuser=0#granular_operations).

Comment: Hi @Renaud Tarnec, so this is the crux of the question in the first place. When I use the rule as you've shown then I am not even able to create a post in the first place.
However if I relax the rule as below then I am able to add a post without any problems.

 {
  "rules": {         
    "posts":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: So I hope you see now what I am saying in the comments above and the problem I am trying to resolve. The rule is looking for a matching uid in the posts collection but is unable to write to the posts collection because the uid does not exist.

If what you're saying is true (that uid is not needed in the posts collection to write) then how would that explain how I am able to write to the posts collection after relaxing the rule but not when the uid requirement is still there. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You are changing the details of your initial question, which is not about the `write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",` rule but about the `".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid", ` rule. You should write another question dedicated to this new case.

Comment: HI @Renaud Tarnec, I am sorry that this is getting confusing. I haven't changed the details of the question I am using the condition write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true" to demonstrate proof that relaxing the rule in my initial question allows me to write. I could use any other rule to demonstrate. For example ".write": true.  The problem will still remain, Why am I not able to write when I have the condtion set as auth.uid === $uid ?

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated?

Comment: Hi @Renaud Tarnec Yes the test user (myself) is authenticated and signed in with google's authentication token. I imagine that is why the condition that has auth != null, works for the rule without the $uid parameter.