# Read and Write rules fail on the Firebase security rules playground although writing works in real simulation

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

**Background**
Dear all I am trying to test that the rule below works. This is a firebase realtime database rule (NOT firestore)

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "tariffs": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The rule should allow me to read regardless of uid as long as I am authenticated. The rule should allow me to write to data that belongs to the authenticated user of the same uid in the tariffs location:
<https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/my project/database/myproject-default-rtdb/data/~2Ftariffs~2F-NekhNFj-Ns56mvBj7IG>

There is only one data set in the tariffs location which is NekhNFj-Ns56mvBj7IG

[image: only one data set in location]

**Problem**
When I tested the rule in the rules playground all four conditions result in a deny (get, set, update or delete). Based on the rule they should result in a read or write in all cases. Interestingly when tested in real life I can write to the tariffs collection.

The uid of the user matches the data in the location I am trying to access. The uid of k5Lh1hfvSwSmNaKfqh4yfl6tsof2 is the same uid that wrote the data at location -NekhNFj-Ns56mvBj7IG

[image: uid for testing is the same as in tariffs location]

Is there something obvious that I am missing? I don’t understand why the test user is not able to read/write their own data in the rules playground?

**EDIT 19:24 GMT 22nd sep 2023:** Including screenshot error of syntax error after trying to reference child of push ID node

[image: syntax error]

**EDIT 6:37 GMT 23nd sep 2023:** Including screenshot still unable to write or read. Firebase rules have been formatted to correct syntax with reference to child of push ID node.

[image: write is still denied]

Comment: In the screenshot of the rules playground it shows `~2F`, but that should be a `/` afaik.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen but unfortunately this didnt work. I've added the screenshot proof in the answer above.

Comment: "this didn't work" is a bit of a shortcut there: the `~2F` are not correct level demarcations here, so they were definitely an issue. There may be more issues, but if you agree this was one of them - it's probably better to replace your initial screenshot with the updated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so after extensive testing I am embarassed to say the main reason I was having trouble with rules playground is because I forgot to tick the "email verified" checkbox as well as add the email in the rules playground.
See screenshot below.

[image: email needs to be there]

Thanks for your patience @Frank van Puffelen.

Additionally for the rules to work as intended in the question, both on the rules playground and in real life, then they need adjusting as below:

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "tariffs": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || data.child('user').child('uid').val() === auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issue with how you encoded the path that I called out in the comments already, the way you use `$uid` in the rules doesn't match with the data.

Your rules say:

```
"tariffs": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid)"
  }
```

So under `tariffs`, you have nodes where the key if the UID of a user, and a user can only write to the `tarriffs` child node with their own UID.

But if we look at your the data in your screenshots of the `tarriffs` node:

1. The node under `tarriffs` seems to have a push ID as its key, not a UID.
2. That push ID doesn't match the UID of the user, so the rule correctly rejects the operation.

If you want to use the push ID as the key for the node, and want to allow writing when the `uid` **property** has the value of the current user, that'd be:

```
data.child('uid').val() === $uid
```

So this checks if the *existing* data in the node where you have this rules clause has a child property `uid` and the value of that property matches the UID of the currently signed in user.

Comment: thanks @Frank van Puffelen, I am not sure how to write your rule into my rule. Is it like this?                                           
 ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (data.val().uid === $uid"

Comment: Also in the screenshot how did you know that node under tariffs is a push ID rather than UID? there doesnt seem to be a difference  when looking at the screenshot as both just reference "uid".  Thanks

Comment: The `$uid` is just a variable name. The value you use in your data is a push ID, meaning it comes from calling `push()` in your code (or `childByAutoId` if you're on iOS).

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen Ok I follow your logic.
If what you're saying is true then why is the $uid variable used as standard in the first place? In fact the firebase documentation states that $uid variable is not a push ID but specifically "the ID of the user obtained through firebase authentication" https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security
I've confirmed the UID used (screenshot) is same as one in authentication tab. Based on these facts I cant see clear evidence for a differentiation between UID and Push ID? Mayb you could point to official documentation that references "push ID"?

Comment: To learn more about the `$` capture variables in security rules, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables --- If you think the documentation isn't clear on this subject, I recommend leaving feedback through the link at the bottom of the relevant page. --- For more on push IDs, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data and **many** more places from https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+push+id

Comment: My apologies @Frank van Puffelen. I now understand where I got confused after reading the documentation. I've found out that push IDs are unique values containing a mix of numbers and letters. When you were referring to the node being the push ID you were referring specifically to NekhNFj-Ns56mvBj7IG which fits this property exactly.  The child of this push ID node would be the UID. So now I need to reconfigure my rules to include reference to this child property. Unfortunately when I tried your suggestion data.val().uid === $uid I got an error (see updated question with screenshot of error).

Comment: Ah yeah, this is one place where rules syntax differs from the equivalent JavaScript. I updated the syntax in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen. I went ahead and reformatted my rules to the correct syntax and there were no more errors. I then re-tested in the rules playground and I am still unable to read or write to the push ID location (I've added a screenshot). Could this be because in the field that says Firebase UID I provided a user's UID instead of the push ID?

Comment: The new screenshot doesn't contain enough info to see what is going wrong (missing the path you're writing, the existing data, etc). Note that by now I've identified two bugs in your rules/code, and we're reaching the end of what we can reasonably do to help on Stack Overflow. Your next step is to **simplify** your rules until they work (remove the `email_verified` check, remove the data existence check, etc), write to a simpler path (as you had issues there), etc --- Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve＆https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example